# What is the size of the <h2> tag?

Tags: xhtml

I need to know the exactly size of the `<h2>` tag. I need that value to apply it to other text which has to have the same size of this tag.

Comment: Well, isn't that something that you specify yourself with CSS?

Comment: Different browsers will assign slightly different style values to raw HTML, and this can affect font-size.  You really need to be assigning values to ensure consistancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no fixed values of font size property for font size intervals. It is implementation-defined. The matter is fairly complex. I'd suggest to take a look at least at graphs presented here: [Toward a standard font size interval system](http://style.cleverchimp.com/font_size_intervals/altintervals.html) by Todd Fahrner

Answer (score 4):

It depends.

You can set it directly by
h2{} in css

Comment: i don't really need to enter in css, i need just the numeric value that represents the h2 tag (10, 11, 12,etc)

Comment: Result may be different in different browser or with different styles(not to h2 only)

Answer (score 2):

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html suggests its 1.5em, or half again as large as whatever the standard font size has been set to.

Answer (score 0):

It equates to 2em on my WordPress theme on desktop display and 1.5em on mobile.